# File path to file on Mac Mini via LAN

Tags: wifi, mac-mini, filesystem, script

I have a bunch of data files on a Mac Mini that I want to read over my wireless LAN in a script (F#, not that it matters I think). I can see the files in Finder, but don't know how to read them in a program.

What path to the file would I use in my script? For example if I had a file called myData.csv in a folder called MyUserId/data, what would the path be?

Comment: How exactly do you reach the files in Finder? Are you using file sharing on the Mini and mounting the shared folder on the other computer, or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly (sorry, should have said). I have a directory with public access on the Mac Mini and when I mount the Mac Mini in Finder I can navigate to it.

Comment: If program is in F# which is a .Net based language what OS is the program running under and how do you connect to the Mac mini from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network volumes get mounted in `/Volumes`. So look for a folder within `/Volumes` that corresponds to the name of your Mac Mini or the network share.

Additionally, you can drag any file into a Terminal window, and its full path will be entered onto the command line.